# Updating an Item results in a Business Validation error - asking me

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to update the purchase costs of our items. The API returns this error

```
A business validation error has occurred while processing your request Business Validation Error: 
Do you want to update existing purchase transactions to use the new purchase account
```

Any idea how I can answer this in the API call?

Here is my API call

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Item xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3 IntuitRestServiceDef.xsd">    
    <Id>598</Id>
    <Name>64-U9K0-92QN</Name>
    <PurchaseCost>22.00</PurchaseCost>
    <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
</Item>
```

Here is the API url being called

```
https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/<<company_id>>/item?operation=update
```

The same error comes from using the API explorer.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the request that leads to that error? How do you access the API? Too few information in here.

Comment: I've added the API call. I'm accessing the API via PHP code. My own integration.

Comment: as the error message comes from the API, you should probably check the API docs

Comment: Thanks, but I've read them thoroughly.  This page should explain it. 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/item

I've also been search on google for about an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  You  need to supply a ExpenseAccountRef in the Update call to pass that validation check. Please update the documentation to state that this is needed to pass validation.

Comment: Hi Sean, It is already mentioned in the business rules- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/item        Business Rules
The item name must be unique.
Sales items must have IncomeAccountRef.
Purchase items must have ExpenseAccountRef.

Comment: Hi Nimisha, Why do I need to supply the AccountRef when it's not changing? I'm just repeating the data for the update the work. Doesn't it make sense that all I'd need is the Id and whatever data I want to change?

Comment: There are many entities where apart from Id and Synctoken, you need to specify some required fields too for QBO V3. I know it's not an ideal behavior but right now that is how this works. Can you drop a support ticket at  https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incidents so that we can verify with the engineering team if this is some new validation that has been added. I am OOO for 2 weeks, someone will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The Api Documentation states multiple fields that are required for an update request that you are not sending, these are; Id (IdType) and SyncToken (String). Add the Synctoken to your request

Comment: SyncToken has never been needed before, but for the heck of it I tried it. Same error occurs.